# RDF API Syntax error

Tags: php, xml, rdf

I am using RAP API for PHP on Netbeans. There is a function named NAMESPACE located at `rdf_api/api/OWLVocabulary.php` and `rdf_api/api/OWLVocabulary.php` 
and the NAMESPACE is creating a Syntax error.

```
function NAMESPACE()
{
    return RDF_SCHEMA_URI;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace is a reserved keyword since PHP 5.3.

You will probably find that the library you're using only works in earlier versions of PHP.

Indeed, it will have worked up to PHP 5.2:
https://3v4l.org/EUqOu